# Getting Error "There is an Error in XML Document (2, 2)" Having trouble getting Zip to City State Lookup with USPS WEB API

Tags: c#, xml, usps

Trying to get a city and state from a zip5 and I can't seem to get the XML right according to the Error I keep getting "There is an Error in XML Document (2, 2)"  when I run it through postman

This is the Service

```
    private const string BaseURL = "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
    private WebClient wsClient = new WebClient();
    public string USPS_UserID = "********";
    public WebTools() { }
    public WebTools(string New_UserID)
    {
        USPS_UserID = New_UserID;
    }
     private byte[] GetDataFromSite(string USPS_Request)
    {


        //Send the request to USPS. 
        byte[] ResponseData = wsClient.DownloadData(USPS_Request);

        return ResponseData;

    }

    public byte[] CityStateLookupRequest(string ZipCode)
    {
        //http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup 

        //  &XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="xxxxxxx"><ZipCode ID= "0"> 

        //  <Zip5>90210</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest> 

        string strResponse = "", strUSPS = "";

        strUSPS = BaseURL + "?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID=\"" + USPS_UserID + "\">";

        strUSPS += "<ZipCode ID=\"0\">";

        strUSPS += "<Zip5>" + ZipCode + "</Zip5>";

        strUSPS += "</ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>";

        //Send the request to USPS. 

        return GetDataFromSite(strUSPS);

        }
}
```

}

I blanked out my user id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System.Net.Http.HttpClient does not contain a definitions for DownloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093071/system-net-http-httpclient-does-not-contain-a-definitions-for-downloaddata)

Comment: I did use webclient and not Http Client

Comment: Since you werent receiving a method not found error, i assumed as much but the selected answer recommends using the httpclient over the web client. Can you try using the httpclient instead?

As an aside, i suspect the reason its throwing that specific error is because you are sending an xml fragment as opposed to a document (i.e. no xml declaration at the top).

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the values of `strUSPS` and `USPS_Request`?  Also, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: I think [Sending xml request to url and receiving xml response back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28932076/3744182) must answer your question.  The accepted answer there is well done because they construct their XML using LINQ-to-XML rather than via direct string manipulation, which ensures it is well-formed.  Does that work for you?